# Gradle bootRepackage task in a project with multiple jars

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I have a project using gradle and springboot.  My project also produces an auxiliary jar of its test classes so that other projects can leverage them.  This seems to send the springboot gradle plugin off the rails.

The docs on the plugin state:

> The bootRepackage task depends on Gradle assemble task, and when executed, it tries to find all jar artifacts whose qualifier is empty (i.e. tests and sources jars are automatically skipped).
>
> Due to the fact that bootRepackage finds 'all' created jar artifacts, the order of Gradle task execution is important.

What I'm seeing instead is that bootRepackage is just repackaging the most recently created jar, not all jars, as the documentation states.  This jar happens to be my jar of test classes, which is obviously not what I want.

Looking through the config options, I can set `bootRepackage.withJarTask` to specify which jar-creating task to use.  If I set that to "jar", bootRepackage will create the correct archive, but still chooses the name of the jar from my test task.

My minimal build script which demonstrates this is as follows.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }    
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0' // random dependency
}

task testJar (type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    baseName = "test-${project.name}" // somehow springboot uses this name
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

configurations {
    testArtifacts
}

artifacts {
    testArtifacts testJar
}

springBoot.backupSource = false
bootRepackage {
    withJarTask jar
    classifier = "boot"
}
```

Assuming my project is named `foo` running bootRepackage with this script, I get a jar named `test-foo-boot.jar` instead of `foo-boot.jar`.  Am I doing something improperly, or does that withJarTask not do exactly what it should?